# How to use the DataContext of a parent class correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

I have a problem with my data binding, probably a small one. I have tried to implement the MVVM pattern in my application. Therefore I have a model containig my data. This data gets updated over the network in a periodic way. On top of this model I have a view model to bind to. In this view model I have a ObservableCollection, which I want to bind. The problem I have is, that my view model needs to be a global resource. Thats why I use the following attempt in my NavigationWindow :

```
<NavigationWindow.DataContext>
    <localvm:DataViewModel/>
</NavigationWindow.DataContext>
```

The reason I have to use it as a global variable is, that this view model starts my network business logic. Thats probably a bad way but I could'nt find a solution to this. Anyway
to diplay my data I have a Frame in my NavigationWindow defined like this:

```
<Frame Source="/Views/Pages/Page1_SystemOverview.xaml" VerticalAlignment="Stretch></Frame>
```

in this loaded page I have a ItemsControl to view the Collection:

```
<Page>
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <localcnv:DebugHelperConverter x:Key="debugCNV"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source=ListOfQuerys}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                        <Button Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>   
</Grid>
```

So here is my problem: When I start my program The ItemsControl contains 18 elements with no content at all. It should contain only two elements, the output window shows me no binding errors, but when I change the ItemsSource to

```
"{Binding Path=ListOfQuerys}"
```

it says:

```
System.Windows.Data Information: 41 : BindingExpression path error: 'ListOfQuerys' property not found for 'object' because data item is null.  This could happen because the data provider has not produced any data yet. BindingExpression:Path=ListOfQuerys; DataItem=null; target element is 'ItemsControl' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought, when I set the DataContext in a parent class, I can use it down the tree but somehow it won't work, any Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `Source=ListOfQuerys` sets your ItemsSource to a `char[]` containing all the characters of that string. You usually do not use `Source` unless with a markup extension like `StaticResource` or when using element syntax.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I know it looks like the query is a string, but its actually a object containig a lot of additional propertys and data, so using a char[] wont do.

Comment: Are you sure you have a public property named `ListOfQuerys` in your `DataViewModel` class?

Comment: Hi, thanks again. Yes I am sure, its declared like this: public ObservableCollection<QueryDataModel> ListOfQuerys;

Comment: See my answer below. Let me know if that helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of the `Frame` element is not part of visual / logical tree and hence will not persist the data context. You will have to set it explicitly.

```
    <Frame Source="Page1.xaml" Navigated="Frame_Navigated"/>

    private void Frame_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        ((FrameworkElement) e.Content).DataContext = this.DataContext;
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: When I change the line to {Binding Path=ListOfQuerys} the error message changes to:    

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ListOfQuerys' property not found on 'object' ''DataViewModel' (HashCode=12416961)'. BindingExpression:Path=ListOfQuerys; DataItem='DataViewModel' (HashCode=12416961); target element is 'ItemsControl' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
 target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: I made it a property using get and set. I thought these are implemented by default when using a ObservableCollection. Maybe you could mention this in your answer, then I will accept your answer as the correct one.
Thank you very much!

Comment: I just use:-     <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" DataContext="{Binding}">

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source=ListOfQuerys}">
```

by

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source=ListOfQuerys, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But it says bidirectional binding needs a Path and thats not working either.

Answer (score 0):

If ListOfQuerys is a property of your datacontext object make the following binding :

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfQuerys}">
```

The source is your datacontext by default, ListOfQuerys here is the path.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! This is the same as using Path=ListOfQuerys and results in the same error.

Comment: Ok, I read to fast. Are you sure the datacontext in your page is set to the correct object?

Comment: No I am not sure, i expect the datacontext to be inherited from the NavigationWindow. Am I wrong?

Comment: The datacontext is inherited through the visual tree so it should be set. I don't understand the problem. Maybe there is a problem with your ListOfQuerys. Is the list instanciated?

Comment: Hi, it is instanciated I can the the output in the console

Comment: AngelWPF seems to be correct. The binding error that results (code:40) indicate that the property ListOfQuerys can't be found on your DataViewModel object. Your property path is probably misspelled.